# Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-query

I just have a general question about setting an Access query to Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates). I know it opens up the fields for editing and this increases the risk of maintaining data integrity, but what about in "controlled cases"?

For example, I have a table on the "one" side of 3 left outer joins. I want to allow edits (via a form) to any fields on the "one" side. The 3 outer joins are merely pulling information from these other tables to use in a calculated field in that query. So I need to show these calculations at this query level, but edit the primary table in the query. I know the changes I'm allowing in the form are just on the "one" side. Is this an allowable case for using Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)? I just can't figure out an appropriate solution. I tried using a subquery for the one field instead of outer joins but that still left it locked.